# Creating, modifying and removing folders and folder structures in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I know that it is possible to delete files from the File Browser view, but is there a way to create, modify and remove folders in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 'file browser' than you probably have the IMCE file manager enabled. What you want to do then is enable the extension module [IMCE_mkdir](http://drupal.org/project/imce_mkdir) to create directories and subdirectories (within folders your web user has permission to access):

> IMCE Mkdir allows users to create and delete sub-directories under
>   directories assigned by IMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Another relevant module, IMCE Tools:
https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_tools